# Building maui app with server side rendering blazor component

Tags: c#, .net-maui, maui-blazor

Hello friends i have an app i want to host blazor components in server side not directly inside the maui app, I've tried grpc signalir ive tried embedio too.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but see if `Maui` has a [**WebView** class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows). That doc is from Xamarin Forms, but it might exist in Maui. IMPORTANT: [BlazorWebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/blazorwebview) will NOT do what you want AFAIK - that is a "Blazor Hybrid" view, showing blazor components that are part of the app bundle.